# SQL 2014 windows 10

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

This alert appears, when I want to open any (`.sql`-) file where I want to create new database or new query.

> Class not registered.
>   Looking for object with CLSID
>   {D8CB03CB-A124-4E7F-9EB2-788F351367A2}

Comment: What application is registered to open files with a `.sql` extension?

Comment: Did you download and install **[SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)** ?

Comment: @PeterB yes I got SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO 2014